# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when connecting to mongodb on AWS using MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

This question has been answered and I tried what was suggested (updated bindIp, security group on EC2 open to 27017 port inbound for 0.0.0.0/0) but may be something has changed.

From AWS, I copy the connection string under the title - `Connect to this cluster with an application`

It looks like this:

`mongodb://username:<insertYourPassword>@docdb-date.cluster-gsatsafaaa.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false`

- I have added my ip to the inbound and outbound rules on AWS
- I modified `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg` and
  changed `bindIP to 0.0.0.0`

I also tried to connect using mongodb for vs code with same connection string and get same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I gave up and deleted the cluster on aws. I then created on Atlas and worked immediately. I will create another cluster on aws and post the whole error because I really would like to use aws. Thx

Comment: @D.SM Just created another cluster and full error listed on compass is  `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clustername.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com` as noted in the title of my post. Appreciate any help !